# select true if more then 0 in t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to perform query in which as a result I have column with false if the value in former column is 0 and true if is greater then 0:

as example:

```
id  count
1   1
2   3
3   0
4   5
5   2
```

result:

```
id   count
1    true
2    true
3    false
4    true
5    true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select 
    id, 
    case 
        when count > 0 then 'true'
        else 'false'
    end as count
from myTable
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select id
    , case when count > 0 then cast(1 as bit) else cast(0 as bit) end as count
from myTable
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the question exactly as asked, but in my opinion a better way to handle true/false +1